# Аналог php-функции number_format

Tags: javascript, jquery

В PHP есть функция [number_format](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php).

> ```
> string number_format (float $number[, int $decimals = 0 ])  
> string number_format (float $number,  
>                       int $decimals = 0,  
>                       string $dec_point = ".",  
>                       string $thousands_sep = ",")
> ```
>
> Функция принимает один, два или четыре аргумента (не три):
>
> - Если передан только один аргумент, `number` будет отформатирован без дробной части, но с запятой (",") между каждыми тремя цифрами.
> - Если переданы два аргумента, `number` будет отформатирован с decimals знаками после точки (".") и с запятой (",") между каждыми тремя цифрами.
> - Если переданы все четыре аргумента, `number` будет отформатирован с `decimals` знаками после точки и с разделителем между каждыми тремя цифрами, при этом в качестве десятичной точки будет использован `dec_point`, а в качестве разделителя групп - `thousands_sep`.

Cуществует ли её аналог в `javascript/jquery`?

Comment: напиши хотя бы что делает эта функция в php. и примеры вызовов и результата

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=number+format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Полного аналога, наверное, нет.

Есть возможность вывести число в соответствии с настройками локали:

```js
console.log(
  Number((-12345.6789).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString(),
  (-12345.6789).toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2}),
);
// Или (новый API)
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Number(-12345.6789.toFixed(2))),
  new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(-12345.6789),
);
```

Также несложно реализовать `number_format` с помощью `toFixed`, хотя во многих случаях решения выше может быть достаточно.

Посмотрим сигнатуру функции на php.net: [number_format](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)

> string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )

Реализация:

```js
function number_format( number, decimals = 0, dec_point = '.', thousands_sep = ',' ) {

  let sign = number < 0 ? '-' : '';

let s_number = Math.abs(parseInt(number = (+number || 0).toFixed(decimals))) + "";
  let len = s_number.length;
  let tchunk = len > 3 ? len % 3 : 0;

  let ch_first = (tchunk ? s_number.substr(0, tchunk) + thousands_sep : '');
  let ch_rest = s_number.substr(tchunk)
    .replace(/(\d\d\d)(?=\d)/g, '$1' + thousands_sep);
  let ch_last = decimals ?
    dec_point + (Math.abs(number) - s_number)
      .toFixed(decimals)
      .slice(2) :
    '';

  return sign + ch_first + ch_rest + ch_last;
}


console.log(number_format(-123.5678, 2, '.', ' '));
console.log(number_format(-1234.5678, 2, '.', ' '));
console.log(number_format(-12345.5678, 2, '.', ' '));
console.log(number_format(12345.5678, 2, '.', ' '));
```

Comment: Уже есть - Intl же всякий.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Intl присутствует в этом ответе

Comment: @Qwertiy, его нет в сафари, вообще нет

Comment: @Grundy, во-перых, уже есть, а во-вторых, есть же полифилл.