# Добавление пробелов в input + ui slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Как сделать, чтоб сразу были пробелы и символ в конце и чтоб при изменении значения бегунка, так же были пробелы с символом, а сейчас получается, только когда с клавы вводишь значение добавляется всё что нужно. Хелп :(

```js
var inp_1 = $('#test');
var slider2 = $('#runner_2').slider({
  range: 'max',
  min: 100000,
  max: 1000000,
  value: 180000,
  step: 20000,
  slide: function(event, ui) { // присваеваем значение бегунка инпуту 
    inp_1.val(ui.value);
    var test = inp_1.val;
    if (ui.value > 100000) { // если были изменения, то показываем шаг 2
      $('.s-calc-step2').css('display', 'block');
    } else {}
  }
});


test.onkeypress = event => {
  // Control buttons
  if (event.key.length > 1) return true;
  test.value = (test.value + event.key)
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ') +
    '₽';
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
<div id="runner_2"></div>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Аналог функции number\_format в JS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743911/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-number-format-%d0%b2-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если понимать вопрос буквально, ты получаешь из слайдера числовое значение и нужно при слайде вывести в инпут это значение + текст?
Если да то вот эту строку

```
inp_1.val(ui.value);
```

замени на такую, где к значению добавится текст:

```
inp_1.val( ui.value + " рублей" );
```

Правда тогда обратное извлечение из значения инпута числа чуть сложнее станет, ведь в нем-то теперь текст, а не число.